# What value to Deploy in the 'recipientType' attribute?

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, email-alert

I want to use a VisualForce Email Template for Email Alerting emails listed in a specific SF email alert.

What **"recipientType="** value should I use if I want the recipients to be defined in the 'Email Alert' Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the 'recipient field' blank and just used the Email Alert action for appropriate distros. The VF email template was triggered and delivered fine.